# How to call a controller action method from JavaScript to get data in Json formats and populated a drop-down list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to make a cascade drop down list i want when user select state then related  district or city drop-down list should populated accordingly but in java-script i don't know how to call my action method properly and how it will get cities data from action method? 
View

```
                    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
                     <script type="text/jscript">

                        $(function () {
                            $('#State').change(function () {
                                $.getJSON('/Lawyer/GetCities/' + $('#State').val(), function (data) {
                                    var items = '<option>Select a District</option>';
                                    $.each(data, function (i, district) {
                                        items += "<option value='" + district.Value + "'>" + district.Text + "</option>";
                                    });
                                    $('#District').html(items);
                                });
                            });
                        });
                    </script>

                    @Html.DropDownList("state", (SelectList)ViewBag.statevalues, new { id="state"}) 
                    <select id="District" name="District"></select>$
```

**Controller :**

```
         'var Statetbl = db.states.ToList();
        List<SelectListItem> stateslist = new List<SelectListItem>();

        var states1 = new List<string>();
        var value = new List<string>();
        foreach (var state_list in Statetbl)
        {
            stateslist.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = state_list.State_Name, Text = state_list.State_Name });

        }

        ViewBag.statevalues = new SelectList(stateslist, "Text", "Value");`
```

**getcities action method:**

```
 public JsonResult GetCities(string Id)
    {
        var state_id = db.states.Where(m => m.State_Name == Id).First();
        //var related_cities = db.cities.Where(c => c.State_id.Equals(state_id.State_id)).ToList(); 
        List<SelectListItem> citieslist = new List<SelectListItem>();
        var cities = new List<string>();
        var value = new List<string>();
        foreach (var related_city in state_id.cities)
        {
            citieslist.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = related_city.City_Name, Text = related_city.City_Name });

        }

        return Json(new SelectList(citieslist.ToArray(), "Value", "Text"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: What problems are you having?

Comment: when i click on state drop down list city or district list not populate it just remain empty..

Comment: Sorry to be harsh but there is a lot of nonsense in your code. Take you controller GET method - `DropDownList()` takes `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` which you assign to `stateslist` but the you  create a new `SelectList` from it (just pointless extra overhead). Similarly in your `GetCities()` method you create a `SelectList` - the client knows nothing about what a c# class is. Again just extra overhead and sending extra data across the wire which you never use.

Comment: Your ajax call should be `$.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetCities", "Lawyer")', { id: $(this).val() }, function(data) {`. Your first options needs to have the `value=""` attribute. Your second dropdown should be generate using `DropDownList` as well etc etc. Have a look at the code in this [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GTYuJV) as an example.